# Why did I not get notified when my post was deleted?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I receive inbox messages when:

- I get a reply from chat room
- my post was edited (only got notified for first edit),
- a comment posted on my post or in response to my comment on another's post
- when there is a message mentioning @Ravan

But I do not get messages when my post was deleted (either by peers or moderators).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume it's for the same reason why there's no notification on closure. Jeff Atwood had once posted an answer for [a similar feature request on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/93842/270345), since deleted. The answer was full of (IMO) rather lame reasons (see [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/93842/270345) for quotes and rebuttals). It's a very highly-upvoted feature request, but it doesn't look like it will get implemented.